# Unable to override li with div or id

Tags: html, css

I want to override list items in #box only without changing CSS style of `li{}` . I think I can only change this by creating new CSS class and apply with `<span>` tags. But for me it's only possible when I apply this new class inside `<li>` tag, so it will only apply to one `<li>`. I'm keep doing this for each list item, which is not the right way to do this.

I want to format li tags within #box id, and leave other li tags as it is.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
ol {
    font-family: arial;
    //background: #000; /*font-size:12px; */
                font-size: 11px;
    color: #066;
 }

a:link, a:visited,a:active {color: #660066;}

table {
    border: none;
    color: #000;
 }

{}

.stylish {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
 }
.sidecorner {font-size: 14px;}

.olcolor {
    color: #039FF0;
}

.myclass, ol.myclass{
    color:#3F6 !Important;

    }

li {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-family: arial;
    color: #666;
 }

#box {
    background-color: #ffcc66;
    margin:20px;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px dotted;
}

.sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 19px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 813px;
    width: 276px;
    min-height: 250px;
    //background: lightgrey;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    height: 417px;
}


#li {
    color: #666;
}
</style>


</head>


<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="body">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <table width="276" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1"  >
        <tr>
          <td height="59" valign="middle" style="background:#660066; color: #FFF; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; font-family: arial; text-align: center;">sdfsdfsdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="middle" style="background:#F2F2F2; color: #666; "><ol style="padding-top:25px;padding-right:5px;padding-bottom:20px">
            <li> Tasdfsdf</li>
            <li>asdf</li>
            <li>sadf</li>
            <li>asdf</li>
            <li>as</li>
            <li>dfsd</li>
            <li>sdf</li>
          </ol>
            <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
<h2>&nbsp;</h2>
    <div id="box">
  <h3>Sample Title</h3><hr style="color:#960">
  <h2>Heading...</h2>

  <ol class="myclass">
       <li>This is the sample text<br>

      </li>

     </span>
  </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: your question is pretty unclear, and to add to that your html markup is wrong and incomplete, so not sure what do you mean. Do you want to style one li and leave all other li unstyled? Do you want to style one li in box div and leave all other li in box div unstyled?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to format li tags within #box id, and leave other li tags as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can apply styles to nested elements below a given ID like so:

```
#box li {
color: blue;
}
```

This will leave other li tags unaffected, but if I understood wrong - correct me in the comments.

Comment: Thank you Null, you understood this write, now I'm able to override li inside #box and other li tags are unaffected :)

Comment: Do we call this `compound id`?

Comment: I'm not sure what the proper term for this is, but few results online indicate you can call it this way, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I have override the li tags inside #box ID by writing a compound id like:

```
    #box li{
           color:#999999;

}
```

Now rest of li tags outside #box ID are unaffected, where I have just applied li {} style.